# Data gets corrupted while migrating from redis to ssdb

Tags: redis, key-value-store, nosql

We have an instance of redis, but it is running out of memory, so we decided to move to SSDB as it stores keys on disk instead of doing it in memory.

To migrate the existing keys from Redis to SSDB we used [this](http://ssdb.io/docs/redis-to-ssdb.html) link.

Once the migration completed we realised the values got corrupted. We have a series of n-bits as my values. While the number of set bits remained the same, their positions changed.

For example, 10010101 got changed to 10001110. We searched for patterns in the deviation but could not find any.

Comment: What are the versions? Redis and ssdb?

Comment: Redis - 2.6.17. SSDB - 1.8.0.